# Why do I get an error using OneSignal on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onesignal

Does anyone ever get the issue where OneSignal does not deliver messages to Angular?

TS

```
constructor(private os: OneSignal){
  this.os.init({
    appId: 'App-ID'
  });
}

onTagHandle(tag: string){
  this.os.sendTag("team",tag).then(()=>{
    console.log("Sent Tag : " + tag);
  });
}
```

I get the error

> [Worker Messenger] [Page -> SW] Could not get ServiceWorkerRegistration to postMessage!

Why is that?

Comment: Well, you haven't written it in the question, so I'll just ask the obvious questions after having glanced at [the documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/angular-setup): Did you add the service worker file to your site and [set `serviceWorker` to true in angular.json](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/angular-setup#troubleshooting)?

Comment: crazy thing. It works now, in a different browser. I actually turnt off notifications and deleted the user in the OneSignal dashboard. The browser **Mozilla** won't give me an option to resubscribe. Seems I may need to delete the first token generated. Probably clear cookies.